# how to avoid rails_param gem modifying the params value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using **rails_param(https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param)** gem to do basic validation, this gem automatically converts a few API parameters like in the below request even if I configured marks to be an Integer, it still accepts String values and automatically converts it to integer, how do I avoid these, I want to throw an error if the user gives a string instead of an integer.

API payload
{
"marks": "20"
}

`param! marks, Integer, required: true`

Comment: Gem's documentation is quite clear: "By declaring parameter types, incoming *parameters will automatically be transformed into an object of that type*" - so this behavior is not a flaw, this is a design decision. If you need different behavior why using this gem then?

Comment: I guess you could patch this yourself (seems pretty straight forward). I would add this to either `Coercion` or `ParamEvaluator#coerce` using a `strict` option.